# On MVC form how can I add validate two fields on form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two fields one called **Age range** another called **Actual Age**,
The  **Age range** is configured as (nvarchar (70)) and got value such as
<1year
1-6year
7-12year and > 18year

so the **Actual age** of child is in (int) such as 1 or any whole number
when end user selected Age range 1-6year 
and type 0 or 7 or larger Actual Age should only allow them to input, that incorrect value should through a message or validation or help on this Actual Age value.

or  when end user selected Age range >18year
 and type anything less than 18 Actual Age should not accept, that incorrect value should through a message or validation or help on this Actual Age value.

or when end user selected Age range <1year
and type only less than 1 on Actual Age should only be allow them to input, if incorrect value should through a message or validation or help on this Actual  Actual Age value.
.

[image: Please have a look at the image by clicking]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Makes "field" required and between range.</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/site-demos.css">
 
</head>
<body>
<form id="myform">
<label for="field">Required, minium , maximum:</label>
<input type="text" class="left" id="field" name="field">
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Validate!">
</form>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script>
// just for the demos, avoids form submit
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      range: [ 
  [0, 1],
  [1, 6],[7, 12],[18,99]
  
  ]
    }
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a horrible user experience. You want them to select a drop down then enter their age?  The drop down shouldn't even exist, it should be auto calculated from the actual age value (and doesn't even need to exist in a database really).

Comment: In addition to Erik's excellent comment - it should be pointed out that a person's age changes from year to year.  Storing a DateOfBirth instead of an age makes much more sense in a database.

Comment: @erkindunyaerkindunya please don't update your question via comments.  You always have access to edit your question and add additional details there.  It's also preferred because then other users don't have to read through all the comments to "get" the question.

Comment: @ Erik, I agree, the user will select age range than enter the value ( the age range and actual age used for reporting purpose) Also age range should be populated from actual age for best practice, due to someone write and designed whole solution that why I have follow  them to fix this, do you have any sample code, many thanks